# Allowing dot/fullstop with numeric value by js keycode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keycode

I am struggling with a simple fact that a method will allow all numeric values including '.'(decimal/fullstop/dot). Here is my method. It is working for allowing numeric values. Not working with `keyCode == 190`

```
function IsNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    var ret = (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57 && keyCode == 190);
    document.getElementById("error_numeric").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
    return ret;
}

<input class="form-control" name="teacher_cnic" value="" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" type="text" placeholder="12345.1234567.1" required>
```

It is being called in an form like this `onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);"`

Comment: We need more code ... in particular, how is `IsNumeric` being called?

Comment: Please check @JeremyJStarcher I have edited the details

Comment: Where is your code to check for the dot?

Comment: @peeebeee that has not been added, but if I add it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide an example that illustrates the problem, rather than one that doesn't - [MCVE]

Comment: Please check @peeebeee

Comment: `keyCode` can't be simultaneously between 48 and 57 as well as == 190.

Answer (score 2):

Change `&&` to `||` for the second test of `keyCode`

```
function IsNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || keyCode == 190);
        document.getElementById("error_numeric").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: thank you! but it doesn't work. i tried this before and again but it is only allowing numeric values.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I got the solution. It is the keyCode which had be set to 46 as I am using onkeypress. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As the event is triggered `onkeypress` , for this event decimal/fullstop/point keyCode is `keyCode=46`

So the function's conditional logic will be as follows,

```
var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || keyCode == 46);
```

And that solves the problem.